# Supersized jQuery plugin doesnt use "thumb" to display thumbnail navigation

Tags: jquery, plugins, supersized

When using the Supersized jQuery plugin (v3.2.7) with "thumbnail_navigation" actived, it does not use the thumbnail image for displaying the next and previous item, but instead a scaled down version of the fullsize image. And yes, I have a "thumb" image included for every image I use with Supersized.

I even downloaded the plugin again and the only change I made was to activate the thumbnail_navigation like this: "thumbnail_navigation : 1" in the supersized function.

The [Supersized plugin documentation](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#thumbnail_navigation) says:

> "If the 'thumb' field for the slide is empty, it will simply scale
>   down the full size image."

So by having a "thumb" image it should also be used in the thumbnail_navigation. Does anyone know why it doesnt, even in the original, untouched plugin code and how to actually display the thumb in the thumbnail_navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

I had to go into the .js file `supersized.3.2.7.js`

I did a search for `prevThumb`

For every instance (i think there were 6) where you see `base.options.slides[prevThumb].image`

change to `base.options.slides[prevThumb].thumb`

That seemed to pull the correct thumbs that I specified. However, I could also have broken something else in the process. All looks fine so far, so I guess we will see.

Hope that helps.